Finding the different zeros of a continuous function
I'm working on Spivak's Calculus and am doing Problem 4 of Chapter 8. Here's the problem:

Suppose $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and that $f(a) = f(b) = 0$. Suppose also that $f(x_0) > 0$ for some $x_0\in[a,b]$. Prove that there are numbers $c$ and $d$ with $a\leq c < x_0 < d \leq b$ such that $f(c) = f(d) = 0$ but $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$ in $(c,d)$

So, first, I started drawing functions that satisfy the conditions at the boundary (that $f(a) = f(b) = 0$).

As suggested by the above diagram, the appropriate value for $c$ would be the final x-intercept before $x_0$ (blue dot). Additionally, the appropriate value for $d$ would be the first x-intercept after $x_0$ (red dot). This is indeed the solution that is given in the solutions manual of the book (although only this fact is stated and a proper proof isn't given).
Now, I want to know how to access the blue and red dots. Initially, I came up with the following strategy:
$$A = \{x:a\leq x < x_0\land f(x) < 0\}\cup\{a\}\qquad c = sup(A)$$
$$B = \{x:x_0 < x \leq b\land f(x) < 0\}\cup\{b\}\qquad d = inf(B)$$
The union would help with the case where the function doesn't intercept the x-axis at all. In such a situation, the first set would be empty and $A = \{a\}$ and $B = \{b\}$. This would make $c = a$ and $d = b$. However, I realized that the above strategy would not work for functions like these:

Clearly, the red dot is where we'd want $c$ to be. However, the supremum of $A$ would be the blue dot. A similar problem arises when finding the first x-intercept from $x_0$.
In essence, by setting $c = sup(A)$ and $d = inf(B)$, I can prove that $\forall x\in(c,d), f(x)\geq 0$. But, the theorem proposed is more stronger. So, how can I prove that $f(x)$ is strictly greater?

In the definitions of $A$ and $B$ impose that $f(x)\le 0$ instead of $f(x)<0$ and you are done.

@Giafazio that was simple. thanks a lot

Clearly f here has to be of degree 4. What about higher degrees? Also, Intermediate value theorem states that $x_0$ exists, but does not say that it has to be positive!

The title needs fixing

Your proposition does work, including @Giafazio's comment. However, it would be much easier and understandable to work directly with the continuity properties at $x_0$:
$f$ is continuous at $x_0$ therefore, by definition, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $\forall x\in [x_0-\epsilon, x_0+\epsilon], ~ f(x)>0$. And as a consequence, there exists $\epsilon_1>0, \epsilon_2>0$ such that $\forall x\in [x_0-\epsilon_1, x_0+\epsilon_2], ~ f(x)>0$.
And from there, you define $x = Sup(\epsilon_1), ~d=Sup(\epsilon_2)$.
